# What's the difference between android and android2 fields in the .xml files?

Tags: android, android-xml

I had this question since android (seemingly) arbitrarily uses "android2:..." in some cases and in others "android:...". Is there any difference between those two?
Also, when using "android2:..", autocomplete feature of eclipse does not work, which can be proven irritating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`android` in the case of `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` is just binding a namespace. You could name it `xmlns:iphone="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` and then reference it like `iphone:layout_width` and it would still work.

Where have you seen `android2` used? I've never seen that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just observed at the top of my xml file these lines: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:android2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
which seems perfectly logic with what you said. The question remains though, why would it automatically produce more than one aliases referring to the same namespace? (I used Android SDK's palette to create my layout by click&drag)

Comment: Looks like your IDE may have just done something weird. You can delete the android1, android2 tags and just replace them all with android. Probably just a bug in the layout generator.

Comment: Question is why do you have `;` after them? Maybe the ADT don't understand the lines because of that and add its own to it. I would just remove them...

Comment: Good catch, too. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Thanks! That clarified things for me. Auto-complete (field suggestion) works as well now that "android2" is replaced with "android". Weird, but that's not the first bug that Eclipse IDE throws at me.

Comment: And it won't be the last. ;) Jump to IntelliJ while you still have your sanity!

Comment: The ";" was added automatically when I copy-pasted the lines here! They do not exist in my layout file! Good observing, though.

Comment: I will consider trying IntelliJ since you propose it after my next project ;)